# Pass a string variable to a comment in a bash script

Tags: 16.04, bash

I'm trying to pass a string variable inside a bash script, but into a comment in the script.

At the command line, I was thinking I could pass it in like this:

```
./script.sh specific_string_variable
```

And then inside my bash script, the comment line would be updated like this:

```
#heres the comment line with this variable inserted: specific_string_variable
```

Is this possible?

Apologies if this is obvious, i'm a beginner. Thank you :)

Comment: What you are describing sounds more like programmatically *editing* the script, rather than passing a variable to it

Comment: This is most probably a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You better rework your question and describe what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to add this following lines inside your script :

```
echo "#heres the comment line with this variable inserted:" $1 >> script.sh
```

Explanation :

- `$1` is your string variable; if you want to use a sentence, there is 2 way :

  - using backslash `\` like `test\ magic\ beautiful` (the `\` say *the space is a character*)
  - using double quote `"` like `"test magic beautiful"` (inside `""`, everything is consider as a *character*)
- `>>` add the text at the end of your script whereas a simple `>` would erase your script and write the text
- the comment must be inside double quote `"`

Here is the script before and after execution :

```
damadam@Pc:~$ cat script.sh 
echo "#heres the comment line with this variable inserted:" $1 >> script.sh
damadam@Pc:~$ ./script.sh test
damadam@Pc:~$ cat script.sh 
echo "#heres the comment line with this variable inserted:" $1 >> script.sh
#heres the comment line with this variable inserted: test
```

and with 2 words string :

```
damadam@Pc:~$ ./script.sh test\ magic
damadam@Pc:~$ cat script.sh 
echo "#heres the comment line with this variable inserted:" $1 >> script.sh
#heres the comment line with this variable inserted: test
#heres the comment line with this variable inserted: test magic
```

Comment: Would continuously add new line on each consecutive execution with comment, but could also easily remove and write new line using this logic. Why you'd ever want to do this is more of a mystery :joy: Also, you could just add quotes around the text you wish in the comment and you'd be free to write without backslashes @damadam `./script.sh "hello world"`

Comment: @Smurfz87 I made simple for OP, but yeah, I could mention the quote way to pass as parameter a sentence (rewrite on the same comment would be a lot heavier, and probably not what the OP wants)